# What is this symbol ($\Vdash$) called?

Tags: notation, modal-logic

This symbol:

$$\Vdash$$

What is it called? It is often used in modal logic, like this: $W\Vdash$. I looked for it in wikipedia/modal logic and wikipedia/logic notation, but could not find it.

Comment: Search in the [list of logic symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols).

Comment: @Nathanson: what is the point of linking a list in which the symbol *does not* even appear?

Comment: It the [forcing relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)).

Comment: nathanson: as stated, i looked there but it is not listed. Thanks to kennytm for editing the post, replacing the image of the symbol with `
\Vdash`, and thanks to mrp for providing the name and a source where it is used in context.

Comment: @zarathustra You think about the answer. It is Wikipedia, "is" or "isn't" don't make sense. It **should** be there. If it is not, it will be added.In a little while, it is your comment the one that is not going to make any sense.

Comment: One can also find this symbol in classical realizability (there $p\Vdash\phi$ is read as "$p$ realizes $\phi$"). I don't know if it has a name, though.